# changing one entry of a matrix and Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be an $ n \times n $ real strictly upper triangular matrix. Suppose we change the entry $a_{nn}$ to be a non-zero real number $z$. My question is, will the Jordan block sizes of the resulting matrix be the same for all non-zero $z$?

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Following a comment from @hardmath I have edited your question to make it more clear.  Please change it back if this is not what you meant.

Comment: @David now the question looks more clear, thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Write $A(z)$ for the matrix which has $(n,n)$ entry equal to $z$ and is otherwise equal to $A$.  Then $A(z)$ has eigenvalue $z$ with a Jordan block of size $1$.  The only other eigenvalue is $0$ and we have to show that the sizes of the corresponding Jordan blocks do not depend on $z$, provided $z\ne0$.

Now the sizes of the blocks are determined by the nullities of $A(z)^k$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$.  If we write $A(z)$ as a block matrix
$$\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}
  A(z)=\pmatrix{T&\v v\cr \v 0&z\cr}$$
where $T$ is strictly upper triangular, $\v v$ is $(n-1)$ by $1$ and $\v0$ is $1$ by $(n-1)$, then it is easy to confirm that
$$A(z)^k=\pmatrix{T^k&T^{k-1}\v v+zT^{k-2}\v v+\cdots+z^{n-2}T\v v+z^{k-1}\v v\cr \v0&z^k\cr}\ .$$
Since $z\ne0$ we can row-reduce by scaling the last row and then subtracting suitable multiples of the new last row from other rows (which only changes the last column) to get
$$\def\nty{\mathord{\rm nullity}}
  \nty(A(z)^k)
  =\nty\pmatrix{T^k&T^{k-1}\v v+zT^{k-2}\v v+\cdots+z^{n-2}T\v v+z^{k-1}\v v\cr \v0&1\cr}$$
and so
$$\nty(A(z)^k)
  =\nty\pmatrix{T^k&T^{k-1}\v v+T^{k-2}\v v+\cdots+T\v v+\v v\cr \v0&1\cr}
  =\nty(A(1)^k)\ .$$
Thus the nullities do not depend on $z$, and this completes the proof.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking, although the confusion is understandable.  I think the OP is asking if changing $a_{nn} \neq 0$ to $a_{nn}'$ (also nonzero) will preserve the Jordan blocks corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ (or, at any rate, their sizes).

Comment: @hardmath Mmm, could be.  Clarification please GA316?

Comment: @David What hardmath telling is correct. for various non zero reals will the size of the blocks remain same? this is my question. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please see the edit I have made to your question, and my new answer.